# How to configure Nagios to send a SMS alert with a cdma Verizon android phone?

Tags: nagios, alerts, sms

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to send an SMS alert using one of our spare Verizon phones.  Since the phones use CDMA,  I can't write a script using the AT commands for sending an SMS on a GSM phone. I have looked on the internet for AT commands to send an SMS  message with a CDMA phone but so far no luck.

Any information would be most helpful.

Thanks in advance,
Gary

Comment: The following certainly isn't a failsafe approach, but I use Nagios for all of my infrastructure monitoring, and am also on Verizon, and I haven't had a problem with this method: Configure Nagios to send an email to your 10-digit phone number @vtext.com. i.e. if your number is 123-456-7890, and you have Verizon, then it would be 1234567890@vtext.com.

Comment: Why not just use one of the hundreds of SMS-as-a-service vendors out there? If you're worried about missing notifications if your internet circuit goes down, all you need is a single nagios outside your network checking your internet connection.

Comment: Hi David, EEAA,  thanks for your suggestions.  They are both good and I will consider them both.